# Split string of numbers into a decimal array?

Tags: c#, arrays, parsing, decimal

Can someone please help me with syntax? I want to parse a string into a decimal array and should be able to do something like this

```
decimal[] test = Convert.ToDecimal("123,345,3".Split(','));

decimal[] test = (decimal)"123,345,3".Split(',');

decimal[] test = decimal.Parse("123,345,3".Split(','));

decimal[] test = "123,345,3".Split(',',decimal);
```

Comment: Why do you want an array?  I'd recommend using a collection type (like `IEnumerable<>`).

Comment: Why would you recommend the usage of `IEnumerable<>` rather than the usage of an array? @ErikPhilips

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
decimal[] test = "123,345,3".Split(',').Select(decimal.Parse).ToArray();
```

or [`Array.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
decimal[] test = Array.ConvertAll("123,345,3".Split(','), decimal.Parse);
```

Comment: 8 seconds later... damn )))

Comment: does that syntax work - select(function) meaning select(x=>function(x))?

Comment: You can also use lambda expressions. I prefer methods if they are already available.

Answer (score 2):

```
decimal[] test = "123,345,3".Split(',').Select(d => decimal.Parse(d)).ToArray();
```